# Pivoting data in R with reshape

Tags: r

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I feel like I'm close to a solution here. I have a dataframe called `Data` which has the column names and data structure like so:

```
Col1, Col2, Col3, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
U,U,A,2,3,9,4
```

I want to pivot this into a form like:

```
Types, Col1, Col2, Col3, Nums
Val1, U, U, A, 2
Val2, U, U, A, 3
Val3, U, U, A, 9
Val4, U, U, A, 4
```

But I can't seem to get the `reshape2` package to work. I've tried:

```
library(reshape2)
melt <- melt(data)
d_melt <- dcast(melt, Col1+Col2+Col3 ~ Val1+Val2+Val3)
```

But this doesn't give the right form of data that I want. Likewise if I reverse the operands:

```
d_melt <- dcast(melt, Val1+Val2+Val3 ~ Col1+Col2+Col3)
```

This also doesn't seem to work.

Am I close? I'm not super great at pivots in R, but I feel like I'm missing some parameter (different tool maybe?) to get a new field name to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`melt` alone achieves the result:

```
melt(df)
# Using Col1, Col2, Col3 as id variables
#   Col1 Col2 Col3 variable value
# 1    U    U    A     Val1     2
# 2    U    U    A     Val2     3
# 3    U    U    A     Val3     9
# 4    U    U    A     Val4     4
```

Comment: This worked for me! The issue on my end was the the numbers were being pulled in as currency and therefore being initalized as factors instead of numerics, which is why I wasn't getting good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `tidyr::gather` instead.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

read.table(text = "Col1, Col2, Col3, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4
                   U,U,A,2,3,9,4", 
                   header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   sep = ",") %>% 
gather(Types, Nums, starts_with("Val"))
```

Result:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Types Nums
1    U    U    A  Val1    2
2    U    U    A  Val2    3
3    U    U    A  Val3    9
4    U    U    A  Val4    4
```